# The type name 'GUI' does not exist in the type 'MyProject'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm pulling my hair out and can't figure out what's the problem.

- Project namespace `MyProject`
- GUI elements namespace `MyProject.GUI`

Inside `MyProject.GUI` there are three elements: `Form`, `Keyboard` and `SelectWrapper`

There we go (no .xaml, just .cs)

```
namespace MyProject.GUI
{
    public class SelectWrapper : Grid
    ...
```

and keyboard cs

```
namespace MyProject.GUI
{
   public partial class Keyboard : UserControl
   {
   ...
```

and keyboard xaml

```
<UserControl 
         x:Class="MyProject.GUI.Keyboard"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

and form .cs

```
namespace MyProject.GUI
{
    public partial class Form : Window
    ...
```

and form XAML

```
 <Window      
         x:Class="MyProject.GUI.Form"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:gui="clr-namespace:MyProject.GUI"

      ...

      <gui:Keyboard
      <gui:SelectWrapper
```

And the compiler (as well as the designer) complains:

> The type name 'GUI' does not exist in the type 'MyProject'
>
> The type name 'GUI' does not exist in the type 'MyProject'
>
> The name "SelectWrapper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProject.GUI".

It doesn't complain about the keyboard tho (only the Form). Please assist.

Comment: Do you have a class somewhere named `MyProject`? I can reproduce that exact error in a project named `Foo` by creating a class `namespace Foo { public class Foo { } }`.

Comment: I don't know how it works in XAML, but you can distinguish classes from namespaces using `::` instead of `.`. What if you wrote `x:Class="MyProject::GUI..."`?

Comment: Backup your XAMLs somewhere. Remove everything between <window></window> and <usercontrol></usercontrol>. Tidy up the attributes. Build the solution. Switch to window's designer. Open toolbox - make sure you see your usercontrol there. Drag-n-drop it to the window. See what does designer do to the attributes. Compare to those you've backed up.

Comment: One more thing - if you want to see `SelectWrapper` in toolbox, it should be in different assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler says `MyProject` is a *type*, I would start with the assumption that there's a type somewhere by that name. I was able to reproduce this by defining a class named `MyProject` in the `MyProject.GUI` namespace:

```
namespace MyProject.GUI
{
    public partial class Form : Window
    {
        public Form()
        { ... }
    }

    public class MyProject
    {
    }

    public class SelectWrapper
    {
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window 
    x:Class="MyProject.GUI.Form"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:gui="clr-namespace:MyProject.GUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <gui:SelectWrapper
            x:Key="test"
            />
    </Window.Resources>
```

> Error CS0426  The type name 'GUI' does not exist in the type 'MyProject'
>   Error CS0426  The type name 'GUI' does not exist in the type 'MyProject'
>   Error     The name "SelectWrapper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProject.GUI".

So I would look for a class by that name in the project, or elsewhere in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `Keyboard` class resides in another namespace, namely `InvoiceFlow.GUI`, doesn't it?

```
<Window      
     x:Class="MyProject.GUI.Form"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:gui="clr-namespace:MyProject.GUI"
 xmlns:kbd="clr-namespace:InvoiceFlow.GUI"
 ...
  <kbd:Keyboard
  <gui:SelectWrapper
```

You need to make sure that there are no other compile errors as well for you to be able to build.

Comment: It doesn't. I did not correct it when pasting it here. My bad